# How can I build the mist-browser and wallet release?

Tags: mist, wallets, installation

My system: Ubuntu

I followed the instructions in https://github.com/ethereum/mist. But after the success command (`gulp mist --walletSource local --platform linux`) execution, I found that the folder `~/mist/dist_mist` is only 12K.

Below are folder details:

[image]

Also I ran the following command to build the wallet:

```
gulp wallet --walletSource local --platform linux
```

But the build process always stops after:

```
[21:00:51] Finished 'switch-production' after 313 μs
```

Do you know the correct steps to build Mist and Wallet on my local Ubuntu system?

Now I am trying to build win32 app. Got build success result. But lots of file under build output directory ~/mist/dist_wallet is missing, include exe and related files. Below is build detail and console output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good, what you are looking for is in `dist_mist/Mist-linux64-0-7-6` (or `linux32` depending on your architecture). Look for binaries called `Mist` or `Ethereum-Wallet` in there and execute them.

By the way, my build script for the wallet does the following:

```
git submodule update --init
npm install meteor-build-client
npm install gulp
npm install
gulp update-nodes
gulp wallet --platform linux
```

Or for the mist browser:

```
gulp mist --platform linux
```

You can ommit the `--walletSource` flag, I think `local` is no valid branch anyways. If you insist on using it, try `--walletSource develop` or `--walletSource master`.

Comment: But I still can not complete the build for wallet. I put the mist and meteor-dapp-wallet source code at the same directory(/home/minxin/). I added build log in question content.

Comment: Not sure why you want to use a local wallet source? Also, it does not look like it stoped but you aborted it with `^C`.

Comment: Hi 5chdn. I resolved some network issue, and got the correct build of linux. But still got same error when I did the build for win32. I attached the log and detail in my question. Seems build completed with no error, build get empty content in build output folder.